# List all participants in a GitHub issue

Tags: github-api

How can I list all active participants (commenters, reviewers, including reactions) in a GitHub pull request?

So far I do

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{issue_number}/comments
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{issue_number}/comments
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{issue_number}/events
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{issue_number}/reviews
```

and for the reactions on issues and pulls reactions

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{issue_comment_number}/reactions
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_comment_number}/reactions
```

for all pull requests needed.

Is there a faster/efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

It is a partial answer. It may satisfy you somehow:

1. Get HTML content with HTTP request `GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{issue_number}`
2. Flush it to a file, namely `issue_html.txt`;
3. Open the file;
4. Search for the keyword "partial-users-participants".

There are 20 participants.